# Recent pages navigator in JSF?

Tags: jsf

I have an interesting idea to implement - I would like to create kind of "history" for user made of recent pages like:
Link1 - Link2 - Link3 - Link4 - Link5
There should be (0-5) links available.

I use only one xhtml page, displaying documents. Lets name it document.xhtml.
For every document.xhtml i attach its id to display, e.g. document.xhtml?id=4.

There are links in each document that leads to another documents (hence the idea).

There is a catch. (or rather catches)

1. When opening a document link in new tab, current page history should be copied to new history and then work separately in new tab.
2. When clicking a link from "recent pages navigator", navigator should be "cut" to clicked page position.
3. It would be best done by not passing parameters in urls.
4. I cant modify document content urls, leading to another documents. These are displayed from plain HTML.

As I use Primefaces breadcrumb to display pages history. I tried to use FlashScope to pass parameters between pages but only using postconstruct annotation. Simmilar i tried to store breadcrumb models in sessionScoped bean, but then it turned into a problem with model identification without "tabScope" identifier.

I don't ask how to resolve this on for me, but for general directions, what jsf elements should I use.
Any "how to approach this problem" will be appreciated.

=EDIT=
Thanks to @BalusC
So far @ConversationScopes seems good to me, but I still have a problem passing data to a new tab. Any ideas here?

Comment: If CDI is available, simply store it in a `@ConversationScoped`. It automatically appends a request parameter to JSF buttons/links to track the scope.

Comment: Thanks for tip, reading about Conversation scope right now :)